# Issues with 'range' in Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, exception

Am trying to modify this script to copy entire rows with the word 'name' in a column to a new sheet.

Got 'Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1' so currently not working at all! Can anyone help?

Thanks

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Admin')
    .addItem('Copy name rows', 'copyNameRows')
    .addToUi();
}

function copyNameRows() {
  const sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Source');
  const targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Target');
  const dataValues = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  targetSheet.getRange(2,1,targetSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 28).clear();
  var currentTargetRow = 2;
  for (var i = 0 ; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    if (dataValues[0][24].toString().toLowerCase() == 'name' ||
      dataValues[0][25].toString().toLowerCase() == 'name' ||
      dataValues[0][26].toString().toLowerCase() == 'name' ||
      dataValues[0][27].toString().toLowerCase() == 'name') {
        sourceSheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, 28).copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(currentTargetRow, 1));
        currentTargetRow++;
      }
  }
}
```

Fiddled with the range values but no joy...As I understand it should check columns 24, 25 and 26 for the word 'name' and if it's there, copy the contents of that row to a new sheet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function copyNameRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const svs = ssh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  tsh.clearContents();//clear sheet
  const n = 'name';
  let o = svs.filter((r,i) => r.slice(24,28).some(e => e.toLowerCase() == n))
  o.unshift(svs[0]);//put header on top
  tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

- [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Update for you comment

```
    function copyNameRows() {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      const ssh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
      const tsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      const svs = ssh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
      tsh.clearContents();//clear sheet
      const n = 'name';
      let o = svs.filter((r,i) => r.slice(24,28).some(e => e.includes(n)))
      o.unshift(svs[0]);//put header on top
      tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
    }
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks Cooper. That does work!! However (my bad for not explaining) I need "name" as a wildcard i.e the cells will contain "name and some other non relevant text"

Comment: @debaron Added modification as per your comment

Comment: Beautiful Cooper! Works like a charm. Thank you very much indeed.